# Formal variables no longer simplifying well on new Mathematica version?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I work with a lot of formula manipulation, modular forms etc. For example, the Dedekind eta function comes up a lot, and I'm often interested in the following sort of code:

```
Eta[q_] := q^(1/24)*QPochhammer[q, q];
FullSimplify[
 Series[(Eta[q^6])^2/(Eta[q]^2*Eta[q^2]^14*Eta[q^3]^2), {q, 0, 12}]]
```

This always used to work perfectly, giving me the simple series in $q$. In fact, I likely didn't even have to use `FullSimplify`. I recently updated to Mathematica 13.0.1, and since then I've had annoying little issues. For example on my end, that code above outputs expressions involving absurd looking powers of $q$ that simplifies to what you want when you do all the cancelling.

I believe it's treating $q$ as possibly a complex number, where this sort of cancellation with fractional powers might be somewhat subtle. But I want to treat it just as a formal variable!! This never used to be a problem...

I know there's a workaround, where you tell Mathematica that $q$ is positive and real or whatever, but that's really annoying. Anyone have any tips here? Any better ways to do this sort of formal manipulation?

Comment: Does using `Normal` give you what you want? That is, `FullSimplify[Normal@Series[(Eta[q^6])^2/(Eta[q]^2*Eta[q^2]^14*Eta[q^3]^2), {q, 0, 12}]]`

Comment: `Simplify[PowerExpand[
  Series[(Eta[q^6])^2/(Eta[q]^2*Eta[q^2]^14*Eta[q^3]^2), {q, 0, 12}]]]` and then `// Normal // HornerForm` as required.

Comment: These changes go back a few versions and came about in an effort to get series correct in punctured neighborhoods of branch points. A way around it is, as you note, to provide the assumption that `q>0`. This can be done in the `Series` rather than in the simplification, in case that makes things easier.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Can I ask the slickest way to include this condition `q>0` in `Series`?

Comment: Actually using `PowerExpand` with nothing else works fine! I guess this is just a minor annoyance I need to remember. Thanks all! (If it's worth making an answer, I will definitely accept it)

Comment: Can be done like so: `In[44]:= Normal[
 ser = Series[(Eta[q^6])^2/(Eta[q]^2*Eta[q^2]^14*Eta[q^3]^2), {q, 0, 
    4}, Assumptions -> q > 0]]

Out[44]= 2 + 1/q + 19 q + 40 q^2 + 213 q^3 + 452 q^4` I'll post a community wiki response in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These changes go back a few versions and came about in an effort to get series correct in punctured neighborhoods of branch points. A way around it is to provide `Series` with the assumption that `q>0`. I also use `Normal` so the result will copy-paste in a readable way.

```
Eta[q_] := q^(1/24)*QPochhammer[q, q];

Normal[ser = Series[(Eta[q^6])^2/
  (Eta[q]^2*Eta[q^2]^14*Eta[q^3]^2), 
  {q, 0,4}, Assumptions -> q > 0]]

(* Out[44]= 2 + 1/q + 19 q + 40 q^2 +
    213 q^3 + 452 q^4 *)
```